# C# How Translate Keyboard Input To Text

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-ce

I am using C# 3.0 in the .NET Compact Framework 3.5 and the program needs to be able to run on both Windows Mobile and Windows CE devices.

I created my own custom text box control. It does not inherit from TextBox or any other type of text box control and doing so is not an option. **How can I translate keyboard input into text so I can properly set the Text property of the control to what the user is typing?** As far as the Text property goes, it is just an ordinary string variable and does not need to be any more advanced than the TextBox.Text property.

I know one way is to subscribe to the KeyDown event and translate the KeyEventArgs parameter into text manually for each character. I am hoping there is a better solution where the translation of keyboard input to text is done for me by the framework or the OS.
Thanks.

What if I was to have an invisible TextBox and channel all the keyboard input to it and set my controls Text property to be the same as the TextBoxe's every time its Text changes. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: is it not possible to embed a real textbox in your control? you dont need to inherit from one

Comment: I can't embed other controls in mine because all the drawing is custom. My control is called AlphaTextBox and it inherits from the AlphaLabel control from the AlphaMobileControls library: http://alphamobilecontrols.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

Translating the keys to a string (not text, as text implies to me things like font, size, location, etc) is not overly complex.  Something like this probably goes a long way toward solving it:

```
public class MyControl : Control
{
    private int m_cursorPos = 0;

    public MyControl()
    {
        Text = string.Empty;
        CursorPos = 0;
    }

    private int CursorPos 
    { 
        get { return m_cursorPos; } 
        set
        {
            if(value < 0) value = 0;
            if(value > Text.Length) value = Text.Length;

            m_cursorPos = value;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Back:
                if (CursorPos > 0)
                {
                    CursorPos--;
                    Text = Text.Remove(CursorPos, 1);
                }
                break;
            case Keys.Delete:
                if (CursorPos < Text.Length - 1)
                {
                    Text = Text.Remove(CursorPos, 1);
                }
                break;
            case Keys.Left:
                CursorPos--;
                break;
            case Keys.Right:
                CursorPos++;
                break;
            default:
                base.OnKeyDown(e);
                break;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(e.KeyChar) 
               || char.IsSymbol(e.KeyChar) 
               || char.IsPunctuation(e.KeyChar) 
               || char.IsWhiteSpace(e.KeyChar))
        {
            Text = Text.Insert(CursorPos, char.ToString(e.KeyChar));
            CursorPos++;
            Debug.WriteLine(this.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you then have to decide how to do the rendering, and if you have multiline support, this won't handle up/down keys.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the [KeyConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyconverter.aspx) class. I don't know if this is part of the compact framework, though.